# Merge [microsoft-bits] and [bits-service]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, synonym-request

[microsoft-bits](/questions/tagged/microsoft-bits) and [bits-service](/questions/tagged/bits-service) seem to be used interchangeably and currently have the same tag wiki (which is just the first paragraph of the Wikipedia entry). As [microsoft-bits](/questions/tagged/microsoft-bits) seems to be used more and is clearer I propose to make [bits-service](/questions/tagged/bits-service) a synonym of that.